# How to show popover when user lands on page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use javascript to show a popup on my page when user lands anytime. Below is how i have it but it is in jquery. Is there a way i can use javascript to achieve this ?

The line `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');` i think is jquery.

PS: Beginner with Jquery and Javascript.

**JS**

```
function displayBox() {
    if(var user == 'guest')
    {$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');}
}
```

Comment: `if(var user == 'guest')` should be `if(user == 'guest')`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bootstrap jQuery. The popover is a function included with the bootstrap library.

You can do this in plain JS

```css
#pop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pop" >Popping</div>
```

More interesting

```js
var user = 'guest';
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  if (user == 'guest') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("pop").classList.toggle("hide");
    }, 1000)
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById("pop").classList.toggle("hide");
    }, 5000)
  }
})
```

```css
#pop {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none
}

.boxshadow {
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #535353;
}

.roundbox {
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pop" class="hide boxshadow roundbox">
  <h1>Popping</h1>
</div>
```